# MAMP PRO WP-CLI Error: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wp-cli

I followed the install instructions at wp-cli.org and am unable to connect to database.  I am using a newly installed (this morning) version of MAMP PRO.

```
which php
/usr/bin/php

echo $WP_CLI_PHP
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin/php

wp --info
PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.5.14
php.ini used:   
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 0.24.1
```

When I run `wp <anything>` in the command line, I get `Error: Error establishing a database connection`

Comment: As MAMP Pro is a commercial, paid solution I would recommend reaching out to their support staff directly instead of posting questions here.

Comment: MAMP Pro is working fine, It's just the WP-CLI that's a problem. I can get to the locally hosted site without issue.

Comment: "unable to connect to database" is pretty vague -- a description of "I did X, and Y happened" that included specific error messages may help someone troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Does the database exist? Are the DB credentials correct in your `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: You're using the php that came with the system and not the MAMP supplied PHP. Add the MAMP PHP path to your bash profile, or similar for your preferred shell, and you should be ok.

Comment: @PatJ his site wouldn't load in a browser if that were the case.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook - updated and now `echo $WP_CLI_PHP` returns
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin/php`

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook - I had updated $PATH, but have reverted it so `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet`

Comment: @PatJ - yes, everything is there and the local site works fine.

Comment: Have a look at http://laurenpittenger.com/wpcli-error-establishing-database-connection-mamp/

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook been there, done that, have a comment awaiting moderation :)

Comment: Is there anything else you've tried that you haven't told us before we put any more effort in?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook All of this: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/317, this: http://ifmeister.com/how-to-solve-wp-cli-for-mamp-errors/, this: https://www.ltconsulting.co.uk/getting-wp-cli-work-mamp/, this: https://wpbeaches.com/install-wordpress-wp-cli-mac-osx/#comment-57872

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook I tried this as well:

`sudo -s`
`curl http://wp-cli.org/packages/pha... > /usr/share/wp-cli.phar`
`echo ‘/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/php /usr/share/wp-cli.phar $@’ > /usr/bin/wp`
`chmod +x /usr/bin/wp`

Answer (score 5):

I noticed a typo in the original answer, but it did work for me in my .zshrc file. The typo was the end of the last line, it was missing the final `/` between the php version and bin directory

```
#MAMP Madness
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Then, to load in the new `PATH` config, run: `source ~/.zshrc` !

Answer (score 4):

I've found it seems to work a lot better if, in wp-config.php you use:

`define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');`

instead of:

`define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: This also worked for me, the other answers did not

Answer (score 2):

Alright - so here's what I figured out.

`~/.bash_profile` should look like this:

```
#MAMP Madness
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Also don't forget to refresh your bash profile when finished with this command: source ~/.bash_profile